# Data logging application, server component - separate thread or separate process?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

I am writing a data logging application which reads some values from an external device and saves them to a file periodically. Also, I would like for the application to have a server component that would make current readings accessible over TCP/IP.

The application is (being) written in C in a unix-like environment.

I am not sure whether the server should run as a separate process (`fork` itself away after start) and use some IPC to obtain the data or whether it would be better off as a separate thread only?

What ingredients go into such a decision?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if existing logging systems on your OS can fit your needs? On most unix-like system you have syslog/syslogng/others. They are made for that, documented, read data from local/network connections, and are also able to forward logs to other machines.

Comment: Should the server just read the file written by the logger, or should it short cut this by sending independently what had been read from the device?

Comment: @alk, the files that the data reside in are a round-robin database sampled each approx. 5 mins, while the server reads "almost real-time" data. So reading it directly from the device is a must.

Comment: @hexasoft, I haven't considered that. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: @hexasoft: At least the syslog-daemons I am aware of are far from (pseudo-)real time.

Comment: @alk: It was not explicitly told in the description! Not sure this is suitable for real-time, you're right. But it may depend on what is real-time: reading real-time is not the same than writing real-time (or serve it outside)

Comment: @hexasoft: My comment was not meant as criticism. In general I fully agree that using existing, well tested solutions are the preferred way to go. Also I agree, that knowing more about the timing- and data-quality/-loss-constrains is essential to provide any meaningful recommendation here.

Comment: @alk: and I well understood your comment. Sorry for the exclamation mark that may have introduce a "over-reacting" feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after real-time, stay away from "another" process as this just introduces another hop in the data path, which slows transmission down.

Have one process, instantiating a reader thread, pulling data from the device and pushing it into an internal buffer, probably implementing [double-buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_with_DMA), depending on the device's capabilities.

Then have a logger thread and a sender thread reading from this internal buffer.

Comment: OK, so the only (or the most important) factor that would go into such a decision would be the delays introduced by the use of a process? I guess my question is a general one, although asked in a very particular context. I don't care whether the data delay is a second or a microsecond; the application is a weather station logger and, when I got the data, they're already aged about half a minute average. But the data are, compared to the RRD 5 minute averaged data points, real-time.

Comment: If latency isn't an hen better have a look at what the syslogd-implementations around could do for you.

Comment: Opps ... the above comment should have read: "*If latency isn't an issue then....*" Sry.